# Find last filled cell in a specific row from a different excel document than what the macro is in

Tags: excel, vba, automation

I am trying to create a macro that reconciles 2 or 3 value of different products from two different excel documents. The first document is produced quarterly, but the cell being referenced will not change quarter to quarter so I can do that. I have no prior VBA expierence but have tried watching some tutorials and the issue I am having is every tutorial is pulling data from the same document the macro is in.

My problem is the second document is produced monthly and the cell I need to reference will shift 1 to the right every month. I think it would be easiest to write code where the last filled cell from this row is selected. I would then replicate this line of code multiple times.

The code I have so far (de-identified file paths, names and sheets for security purposes) works if I put a specific cell in after the $. I cannot figure out the syntax of selecting the last row in the cell. Do I have to declare a variable = the last part of my below formula and reference the variable (I tried that and also didn't work)?

```
Sub LRValuesRefresh()

    Dim Jumpoff_YrMonth As String

    Jumpoff_Month = Range("B2").Value

    With Range("D9")
        .Formula = "='\\drive\drivename\month\datatype\specific_report\[Report_Name " & _
           Jumpoff_Month & " Acct_Standard.xlsb]Product Name'!$" & _
           Range("DI27").End(xlToRight).Column
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What does "the last row in the cell" mean?

Comment: If you need to find the last cell in the row then you'll first need to open the file being linked to...

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following you correctly, you need to open the workbook and find the last-populated cell in row 127 on the sheet of interest:

```vb
Sub LRValuesRefresh()

    Dim Jumpoff_Month As String, ws As Worksheet, wb As Workbook
    Dim fPath As String, addr As String

    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'or some specific worksheet
    Jumpoff_Month = ws.Range("B2").Value
    
    fPath = "\\drive\drivename\month\datatype\specific_report\Report_Name " & _
             Jumpoff_Month & " Acct_Standard.xlsb"
    
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fPath, ReadOnly:=True) 'open the workbook
    
    'get the address of the last cell in row 127
    addr = wb.Worksheets("Product Name").Cells(127, Columns.Count) _
             .End(xlToLeft).Address(True, True, external:=True)
    Debug.Print addr
    
    ws.Range("D9").Formula = "=" & addr
    
    wb.Close savechanges:=False  'close without save

End Sub
```